# Zoom instance for ReaderT IORef

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-lens, ioref

I'm new to lens and having trouble implementing the Zoom instance for this type:

```
newtype MyStateT s m a = MyStateT
    { unMyStateT :: ReaderT (IORef s) m a
    } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

instance (MonadIO m) => MonadState s (MyStateT s m) where
    get = MyStateT $ ReaderT $ liftIO . readIORef
    put x = MyStateT $ ReaderT $ \ref -> liftIO $ writeIORef ref x
```

I've been trying to make a new IORef with the lens substate, run the ReaderT on that substate, and then grab the changed substate and replace it in the main IORef:

```
type instance Zoomed (MyStateT s m) = Focusing m
instance (Monad m) => Zoom (MyStateT s m) (MyStateT t m) s t where
    zoom l (MyStateT r) =
        MyStateT $ ReaderT $ \ref -> do
            s <- liftIO $ readIORef ref
            ref' <- liftIO $ newIORef $ s ^. l
            let v = runReader r ref'
            subS' <- liftIO $ readIORef ref'
            let s' = s & l .~ subS'
            liftIO $ writeIORef ref s'
            return v
```

`l` seems to be different from a normal lens so `^.` and `.~` doesn't compile with it and I get errors like this:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Focusing m c t’ with ‘Const s t’
  Expected type: Getting s t s
    Actual type: LensLike' (Zoomed (MyStateT s m) c) t s
   • Couldn't match type ‘Focusing m c t’ with ‘Identity t’
  Expected type: ASetter t t s s
    Actual type: LensLike' (Zoomed (MyStateT s m) c) t s
```

Can anyone help me get this Zoom instance to work properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

```
type instance Zoomed (MyStateT s m) = Focusing m

instance (MonadIO m) => Zoom (MyStateT s m) (MyStateT t m) s t where
    zoom l (MyStateT r) =
        MyStateT $ ReaderT $ \ref -> do
            s <- liftIO $ readIORef ref
            (v', s') <- unfocusing . flip l s $ \t -> Focusing $ do
                ref' <- liftIO (newIORef t)
                v <- runReaderT r ref'
                t' <- liftIO (readIORef ref')
                return (v, t')
            liftIO $ writeIORef ref s'
            return v'
    {-# INLINE zoom #-}
```

The problem you were having with `(^.)` and `(.~)` is that they work for `Lens`, which is polymorphic in the functor. But here the functor is fixed to be `Zoomed (MyState s m) c`, which is `Focusing m c`. So you need to apply `l` directly using function application.

Note: You need to be a bit careful with this implementation. `IORef` ins't atomic, unless you use `atomicModifyIORef` on a pure function (which doesn't seem possible in `zoom`). So it might make sense to use `MVar` with `takeMVar` and `putMVar` instead, to make sure your computations work correctly when running in a multi-threaded environment.